# Casting a map fragment to Mapview in android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, fragment, android-mapview

I'm working on an application which allows users to select a specific location on the map and save it's coordinates.
I'm using a MapsActivity like this:

```
package com.example.getfamiliarwiththemap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static com.example.getfamiliarwiththemap.R.id.map;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Button ok;

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Create pin
        ImageView pin = new ImageView(MapsActivity.this);
        pin.setImageResource(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_light);
        // Position pin
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        parameters.bottomMargin = (int) (12 * density);
        pin.setLayoutParams( parameters);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map) ;

        mapView.addView( pin);





        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





            }
        });



        if (mMap != null){
            Marker hamburg = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                    .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(KIEL)
                    .title("Kiel")
                    .snippet("Kiel is cool"));
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"You clicked a marker named " + marker.getTitle().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
        }
    }
}
```

But this line is obviously not working:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map) ;
```

How should i cast a mapFragment to a Mapview to be able to add views? I'm pretty new to android so any simple answer would be appreciated.

****Solved**** The final XML:

P.S: My XML layout code:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.getfamiliarwiththemap.MapsActivity" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mLlayoutBottomButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button

    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:textColor="#ffec00"
    android:background="#b600ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"

    />

    </LinearLayout>

</fragment>

    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your xml layout a MapView like this:

```
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you declare a mapview in the XML layout directly?

Comment: Because i don't know how.In fact i didn't even know that was an option till right know! Can you please specifically type in the code?